# Wix Toolset Getting Condition to work for installing a service as auto start or disabled

Tags: wix

I have a Wix Toolset (3.11) msi installer where I am trying to install a service as auto start or disabled. To do this I have a dialog with radio buttons that are used to set a public property:

```
    <Property Id="RUN_TYPE" Value="RunIIS" />
```

Its values are RunIIS (to use IIS for hosting), or SelfHosted to run as a service.

Then there is a Wix Dialog to allow the user to choose hosting method

```
  <Control Id="RadioButtonGroupID" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="30" 
           Y="50" Width="305" Height="125" Property="RUN_TYPE">
                    
    <RadioButtonGroup Property="RUN_TYPE">
        <RadioButton Value="SelfHosted" X="0" Y="0" Width="300" 
                     Height="10" Text="!(loc.SelfHosted)" />
        <RadioButton Value="RunIIS" X="0" Y="20" Width="300" 
                     Height="10" Text="!(loc.RunIIS)" />
    </RadioButtonGroup>
 </Control>
```

An asp.net windows service is used for self-hosting. I have tried to
use the **Condition** element to install the service as either auto or disabled

```
      <Component Id="MyServiceComponentAuto" Directory="BIN_FOLDER"  
                 MultiInstance="yes"
                 Guid="{04EAB7AF-2DC5-4807-85D7-BA9CDE65FD82}" >

        <Condition><![CDATA[RUN_TYPE = "SelfHosted"]]></Condition>
          
          
        <File Id="MyServiceExeAuto" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" 
              Source="$(var.BinFilesSourcePath)\MyService.exe" />


        <ServiceInstall
          Id="MyServiceInstallerAuto"
          Name="My Service"
          DisplayName="My Service"
          Type="ownProcess"
          Start="auto"
          ErrorControl="normal"
          Description="MyService for Web API"
          Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"
          Vital="yes"
          Interactive="no" />


        <ServiceControl
          Id="MyServiceAuto"
          Name="My Service"
          Remove="uninstall"
          Start="install"
          Stop="both"
          Wait="yes" />

      </Component>

      <Component Id="MyServiceComponentManual" Directory="BIN_FOLDER"  
                 MultiInstance="yes"
                 Guid="{543EB05A-5597-428A-B049-E0B454983EA6}" >

        <Condition><![CDATA[RUN_TYPE = "RunIIS"]]></Condition>
          
          
        <File Id="MyServiceExeManual" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" 
              Source="$(var.BinFilesSourcePath)\MyService.exe" />


        <ServiceInstall
          Id="MyServiceInstallerManual"
          Name="My Service"
          DisplayName="My Service"
          Arguments="-service"
          Type="ownProcess"
          Start="disabled"
          ErrorControl="normal"
          Description="MyService for Web API"
          Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"
          Vital="yes"
          Interactive="no" />


        <ServiceControl
          Id="MyServiceManual"
          Name="My Service"
          Remove="uninstall"
          Stop="both"
          Wait="yes" />

      </Component>
```

And this did nothing, the service was not created at all and the file was not installed in either case.

Then I kept only the start disabled and removed the condition completely and tried to set the start property using a registry value

```
      <Component Id="MyServiceComponentManual" Directory="BIN_FOLDER"  
                 MultiInstance="yes"
                 Guid="{543EB05A-5597-428A-B049-E0B454983EA6}" >

        <File Id="MyServiceExeManual" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" 
              Source="$(var.BinFilesSourcePath)\MyService.exe" />


        <ServiceInstall
          Id="MyServiceInstallerManual"
          Name="My Service"
          DisplayName="My Service"
          Arguments="-service"
          Type="ownProcess"
          Start="disabled"
          ErrorControl="normal"
          Description="MyService for Web API"
          Account="NT AUTHORITY\LocalService"
          Vital="yes"
          Interactive="no" />


        <ServiceControl
          Id="MyServiceManual"
          Name="My Service"
          Remove="uninstall"
          Stop="both"
          Wait="yes" />

      </Component>

      <Component Id="MyServiceStart" Directory="BIN_FOLDER" 
                 Guid="{9BCCFB49-FA8D-4A10-BCF2-38660B787B46}" 
                Permanent="yes">
          
        <Condition><![CDATA[ RUN_TYPE = "SelfHosted" ]]></Condition>

          <RegistryKey 
            Root="HKLM"
            Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\My Service" >
              
              <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="Start" Value="2" />
              <RegistryValue Type="integer" Name="DelayedAutostart" 
                             Value="0" />
          </RegistryKey>
```

And this did not work either. Am I using **Condition** the wrong way, is there a problem with the Condition statement, or is there another way to go about this?

**Update**

I ran verbose logging and I see RUN_TYPE get set to SelfHosted but other than that nothing. Is there a way to see condition evaluation?

**Update 1**

I gave up trying to get Condition to work and added a custom action and set the startup type using the registry

Comment: A verbose log file will allow you to follow the property's value and see the condition evaluation. Hard to guess what the issue is otherwise.